# How to transfer attributes from source mesh to distributed points?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's say I have a Vertex group, that controls a point distribution:

[image]
*Point scale disabled because it doesn't work as expected*

But if I want to scale points by this Vertex group, I can't do it, because  distributed points lost all attributes from source mesh. Any way to get them back?

UPD.

Distributed points lost all attributes from source mesh in 2.92, but not in 2.93:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Geometry Nodes* does not delete any attribute e.g., *Vertex Weight (Group)*, however, it can override it or create a new one.

**For Blender 2.93:** In your example, to control the scale of the points you have to control the *radius* attribute of the points. So, you can assign the weight from the *Group* attribute to the *radius* attribute with the help of the *Attribute Math* node,
[image]

Comment: Ok, now I got it. You are using 2.93 alpha, not the stable one. Rephrase your answer and I will set it as correct.