# Why is my Geometry Node Setup not working?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I´m currently trying to create a very simple effect using the new Geometry Nodes.

[image]
This is my Node setup but it doesn´t work. The Mesh gets displayed by the collection but the effect I want to achieve is not showing. The Vertex group should work as the factor but it doesn´t seem to work. It is mixing between a small and a big version of the Instances.

The effect: I have a proximity Vertex Group (Weight Map) which is getting controlled by an empty. When the empty gets closer to the Surface of the Object, the Weight Map is getting stronger.
[image]

And the Goal of the Node Setup is to have a scaling effect happening, using the Proximity vertex Group as the factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use Vertex group, but in 2.92 vertex groups lose after point distribute.

To get this result you need to use 2.93 Alpha: [How to transfer attributes from source mesh to distributed points?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213421/how-to-transfer-attributes-from-source-mesh-to-distributed-points)

Also in 2.93 you can find the Attribute Proximity node, that's the same thing roughly.